# Adding a URL Value to a String in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am having issues.
The script runs and builds the `String` and can Parse the Results, It receives a Accept Automatically then it searches for a value for `RedirectURL`.

How do i add a URL value to be build in the build version of my script.

```
    Friend Overrides Function Filter() As String

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        Return sb.ToString()   '' Returning an empty string allows the applicant to be passed to the lender; otherwise the applicant is not sent

        If app.BankAccount = String.Empty Then
            sb.Append("Bank Account must be present;")
        End If

        If app.BankSortCode = String.Empty Then
            sb.Append("Sort Code must be present;")
        End If

        If app.LoanAmount = String.Empty Then
            sb.Append("Loan Amount must be present;")
        End If

    End Function

    Friend Overrides Function Build() As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()


        sb.AppendLine("&first_name=" & app.FirstName)
        sb.AppendLine("&surname=" & app.LastName)
        sb.AppendLine("&dob=" & app.DOB.ToString)
        sb.AppendLine("&email=" & app.Email)
        sb.AppendLine("&home_phone=" & app.LandPhone)
        sb.AppendLine("&mobile_phone=" & app.MobilePhone)
        sb.AppendLine("&postcode=" & app.PostCode)
        sb.AppendLine("&affid=" & app.affID)
        sb.AppendLine("&subid=" & lendertier.Credential1)
        sb.AppendLine("&leadid=" & lendertier.Credential2)
        sb.AppendLine("&bk_no=" & app.BankAccount)
        sb.AppendLine("&bk_s=" & app.BankSortCode)
        sb.AppendLine("&ar=" & app.LoanAmount.ToString)



        Return sb.ToString()



    End Function

    Friend Overrides Function ParseResult(ByVal sResult As String) As Boolean
        app.Outcome.RedirectURL = sResult
        AcceptLead()
        Return True

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question isn't overly clear but I'll give it a shot...

I think you are after retrieving the application version number and including it in the paramaterse  in which case you will need something like:-

```
Dim versionNumber As Version

versionNumber = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

You will have to import System.Reflection for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i figured it out.

Comment: Was it what you were after?

Comment: I needed to convert the html in the string value to xml : Friend Overrides Function PostToLender(ByVal sData As String) As String
            Return sData
        End Function